# How to Continue Enumerate Across Columns in Beamer

Tags: beamer, lists, enumerate, columns

I am trying to create two columns of a single enumerated list on a single frame in beamer. How do I go about getting the enumeration to continue from one column to the next?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The usual way to resume lists is to use the `enumitem` package, but this doesn't work very well with beamer. So in this case, the easiest way to do this is to define a counter to store the enumeration number in the one column and restore it at the beginning of the enumeration in the next column:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newcounter{savedenum}
\newcommand*{\saveenum}{\setcounter{savedenum}{\theenumi}}
\newcommand*{\resume}{\setcounter{enumi}{\thesavedenum}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}[T]
  \begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item First item
    \item Second item
    \saveenum
  \end{enumerate}
  \end{column}
  \begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \resume
    \item Third item
    \item Fourth item
  \end{enumerate}
  \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome, just what I was looking for!

Comment: @PatrickT What do you mean? Can you explain what you tried to do that didn’t work?

Comment: @AlanMunn, I don't know, I just spent 30 minutes trying to make a minimal example, but the minimal examples always work. If I find out what the problem is, I'll report back... Thanks for asking!

Comment: What about continuing numbering for subitems?

Comment: @AbdelhakElfengour It's not quite clear how that would work. This solution works by starting a new list and then resetting the number, so it's not literally splitting the list.  But you can't continue a subitem list the same way because it needs to be embedded in a split list and you can't achieve that in the same way.

Answer (score 10):

Environments like `enumerate` will have to be split across other environments - `column` in this case since `\begin{<env>}` and `\end{<env>}` have to remain grouped. However, you can also specify the enumerate number **manually** in the usual way you would for lists:

```
...
\begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item<1->[1.] First item
    \item<2->[2.] Second item
    ...
    \item<5->[5.] Fifth item
  \end{enumerate}
\end{column}
\begin{column{.5\linewidth}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item<6->[6.] Sixth item
    \item<7->[7.] Seventh item
    ...
    \item<10->[10.] Tenth item
  \end{enumerate}
\end{column}
...
```

[image: Enumerate across columns in beamer]

Definitely not as elegant as [Alan's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25710/how-to-continue-enumerate-across-columns-in-beamer/25712#25712), but works in a pinch.

Comment: Elegance is sometimes overrated :-)

Comment: It IS elegant. Usually in Beamer you have a limited number of enumeration items. The whole point of enumeration is that it is automatic. Not usually needed in Beamer.