# How to resume the enumerate on different slides in beamer?

Tags: beamer, enumerate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Continue Enumerate Across Columns in Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25710/how-to-continue-enumerate-across-columns-in-beamer)

It seems to be a simple question but I can't find the way out and can't find the solution on Internet as well. I try to resume enumerate in the next slide in beamer but it does not work (I have tried to use enumitem but does not work as well). How can I fix it?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usetheme{default}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]

\begin{document}
\maketitle

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Example 1
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Example 1}

\begin{enumerate}
\item What is the apple?
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Example 1
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Example 1}

\begin{enumerate}
\item What is the orange?
\vfill
\item What is the watermelon?
\vfill
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: We've had a few similar questions on this in the past, maybe you could take a look and see if any of them would answer your question (and if not, it would be useful to explain what goes wrong).  I'll post links as I find them, starting with: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25710/86

Comment: Alan Munn's method (in the link shown by Andrew) works not only across columns, but also across frames.

Comment: Thanks. Yes Alan Munn's method works for me perfectly. many thanks

Comment: Closed based on OPs comment