# Resume Enumeration across frames

Tags: beamer, enumerate

I've tried the equivalent of the question [Resuming a list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1669/resuming-a-list) when the two `enumerate` environments are on two different frames, but compiler will complain.

I.e.

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A Survey of Computer Vision}
\framesubtitle{Fundamental Tasks of Computer Vision I}

\begin{enumerate}

\item one

\end{enumerate}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A Survey of Computer Vision}
\framesubtitle{Fundamental Tasks of Computer Vision II}

\begin{enumerate}[resume]

\item two    
\end{enumerate}

\end{frame}
```

produced the following error:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255].
\labelenumi ->{
\labelenumi }
l.255 \end{frame}
If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.
```

What is the correct way of doing so?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that also the second solution proposed in [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1669/resuming-a-list) won't work...

Comment: `enumitem` and `beamer` doesn't like each other. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31505/trouble-combining-enumitem-and-beamer

Comment: @percusse - I c...and so, in my particular case what should I do?redefine the enumerate command?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This works for me:

```
\newcounter{sauvegardeenumi}
\newcommand{\asuivre}{\setcounter{sauvegardeenumi}{\theenumi}}
\newcommand{\suite}{\setcounter{enumi}{\thesauvegardeenumi}}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A Survey of Computer Vision}
\framesubtitle{Fundamental Tasks of Computer Vision I}

\begin{enumerate}

\item one

\asuivre

\end{enumerate}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A Survey of Computer Vision}
\framesubtitle{Fundamental Tasks of Computer Vision II}

\begin{enumerate}

\suite

\item two    
\end{enumerate}

\end{frame}
```

Comment: thks...without including any particular package?

Comment: works!thk you!can you please explain me why is it working?setting a global counter solved the problem or what else?

Comment: This is standard LaTeX : creating a counter, saving the enumerate counter to it when needed then resuming from it.

Comment: To use this beyond two frames :: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55001/18678