# What do \suite and \asuivre commands when resuming enumerationa cross frames?

Tags: enumerate

I am following [Resume Enumeration across frames](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85509/resume-enumeration-across-frames)

the author has mentioned the use of `\suite` and `\asuivre` to enable the resume of enumeration across different frames.

What do `\suite` and `\asuivre` commands do?

I have to create an enumeration list that expands four frames. I have been trying \suite and \asuivre but the numbering that I am getting is incorrect.

For example, sometimes I get the sequence `{1,2,3,4}{1,2,3,4}{1,2,3,4}{1,2,3,4}`
In some other combination, I end up getting `{1,2,3,4}{5,6,7,8}{1,2,3,4}{5,6,7,8}`

In one of the combinations I even got `{1,2,3,4}{1,2,3,4}{5,6,7,8}{9,10,11,12}`

where `{}` represent one frame and the number represents the order of the enumeration list

I basically do not know when to write `\suite` or `\asuivre` and when to NOT write it. Kindly help

Comment: kindly help me with the concept; I can code the stuff myself

Answer (score 1):

The `\asuivre` command saves the current value of the (top level) enumeration counter.  `\suite` sets the same counter to the saved value.  So at the end of the first list, save with `\asuivre`, then start the next list with `\suite`.  Repeat as necessary.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcounter{sauvegardeenumi}
\newcommand{\asuivre}{\setcounter{sauvegardeenumi}{\theenumi}}
\newcommand{\suite}{\setcounter{enumi}{\thesauvegardeenumi}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item One
  \item Two
  \item Three
  \item Four
    \asuivre
  \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \suite
  \item Five
  \item Six
  \item Seven
  \item Eight
    \asuivre
  \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \suite
  \item Nine
  \item Ten
  \item Eleven
  \item Twelve
    \asuivre
  \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \suite
  \item Thirteen
  \item Fourteen
  \item Fifteen
  \item Sixteen
  \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Sample output]