# Continuing example Counters in Beamer

Tags: beamer, environments, examples

I wonder how to get automated continuing example counters in Beamer. Below is my MWE. Thanks for your help.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}


\setbeamertemplate{theorem}[ams style]
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{example}
  This is a test example
   \end{example}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \setcounter{example}{2}
  \begin{example}
   Continued  previous example.
  \end{example}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**UPDATE**

I'm looking automated continuation of example counter like this one [Continuing enumerate Counters in Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55001/4821). Thanks

Comment: Remove the line `\setcounter{example}{2}`.  Everything should work fine.

Comment: Thanks @A.Ellett for your comment. Following your suggestion I will get Example 1.1 on frame 1 and Example 1.2 on frame 2. But I need Example 1.1 on both frames automatically. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Define a "continuation example" environment:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\setbeamertemplate{theorem}[ams style]
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]
\newenvironment{example*}
  {\addtocounter{theorem}{-1}\example}
  {\endexample}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{example}
  This is a test example
   \end{example}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{example*}
   Continued  previous example.
  \end{example*}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{example*}
   Continued  previous example.
  \end{example*}

  \begin{example}
   New example.
  \end{example}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please point out why for this particular environment (example), `\theexample` or `\value{example}` works fine, but whenever we try to manipulate the example counter, e.g., `\addtocounter{example}{-1}`, the counter is termed as undefined.

Comment: @MMA There is no `example` counter and `\theexample` expands to `\thetheorem`.

Comment: Indeed, if I have an `example` environment, followed by a `theorem' environment, the later is numbered $n+1$, where, $n$ is the number of the first one. Any way to keep these independent?

Comment: You can define new theorems with `\newtheorem`, see section 12.4 in the documentation.

Comment: what's the easiest way to automatically ask beamber to number the examples within sections? for example, 1.1-1.2-1.3,2.1-2.2-2.3 ....2.14, 3.1, ect.

Answer (score 4):

The following is a mild generalization of [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123491/5764) that allows for "continuing examples" mixed inbetween the regular flow of examples. I'm not convinced that this is a valid use-case, since continued examples will typically follow one another from one slide/`frame` to the next, but it may serve some purpose in a bigger context:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamertemplate{theorem}[ams style]
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]
\makeatletter
\def\@firstoffive#1#2#3#4#5{#1}%
\newenvironment{example*}[1][\relax]
  {\begingroup\ifx#1\relax% No optional argument
   \else% Optional argument given
     \@ifundefined{r@#1}{}{%
       \protected@edef\cont@example@num{\csname r@#1\endcsname}%
       \expandafter\edef\expandafter\cont@example@num\expandafter
         {\expandafter\@firstoffive\cont@example@num}%%
       \renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\cont@example@num}}%
   \fi\addtocounter{theorem}{-1}% Revert to previous theorem count
   \example}
  {\endexample\endgroup}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{example}
    This is a test example.
  \end{example}

  \begin{example*}
    This one continues.
  \end{example*}

  \begin{example}
    Another example.\label{myexample}
  \end{example}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{example}
    This is a test example.
  \end{example}

  \begin{example*}[myexample]
    Continued previous example.
  \end{example*}

  \begin{example}
    Another new example.
  \end{example}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The continued example environment `example*` now comes with an optional argument that should contain a reference to a `\label` set in the example that should be continued. If no argument is given, `example*` acts as expected and continues the previous `example`.

Answer (score 3):

Try overlays:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}


\setbeamertemplate{theorem}[ams style]
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\only<1>{  \begin{example}
  This is a test example
   \end{example}
}
\only<2>{
  \begin{example}
   Continued  previous example.
  \end{example}}
  \begin{example}
   Another  previous example.
  \end{example}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{example}
   Another  previous example.
  \end{example}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Only I can can't see 1.1 but 1 as you stated in the comments. So you possibly used another code?

## No. 2

Saves counter, and sets counter to the saved value. Usage: `smyex` is the parent while `emyex` is the child which has the same number, until the next use of `smyex` . Hope this is what you understand under automation.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}


\setbeamertemplate{theorem}[ams style]
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]
\newcounter{extemp}
\newcounter{restoretemp}



\newenvironment{smyex}{\setcounter{extemp}{\theexample}\begin{example}}%
{ \end{example}}
%
\newenvironment{emyex}{%
\setcounter{restoretemp}{\thetheorem}
\setcounter{theorem}{\theextemp}  
\begin{example}%
}{\end{example}\setcounter{theorem}{\therestoretemp}
}



\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{example}
  This is a test example
   \end{example}

  \begin{smyex}
  Previous example.
  \end{smyex}

  \begin{example}
   Another  previous example.
  \end{example}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{example}
  This is a test example
   \end{example}

  \begin{emyex}
   Continued  previous example
  \end{emyex}

  \begin{example}
   Another  previous example.
  \end{example}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is good workaround but still not automated way.