# Making reference using \ref{name} rather than directly name

Tags: cross-referencing

This is continuation of [Continuing example in Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/447621/continuing-example-in-beamer). The answer by @samcarter works, but there is a loose end: making reference to Example 1 in the continuing example is done by "[myexample]". I was wondering if we can replace it with "[\ref{myexample}]" by modifying the preamble. This makes life a little easier because WinEdt then suggests a list of label after typing the first few letters. Thanks!

Comment: \ref is protected.  Try \getrefnumber instead (see oberdiek/refcount documentation).

Comment: I just posted an answer to your question [Counting example in Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/448088/118714) which does also address your requirement of using `\ref`.