# enumitem problem for resume

Tags: beamer, enumerate

I want to use resume in my beamer presentation, so I declared using the package `enumitem`, but I had an error:

> ! Undefined control sequence.
>    .../enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix

I don't know where the problem is!

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

 \begin{frame}
   \begin{enumerate}
     \item one
     \item two
   \end{enumerate}
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}
   \begin{enumerate}[resume*]
     \item three
   \end{enumerate}
 \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

if I don't use `enumitem` I receive this when compiling

> resume* three

Comment: i didn't understand this solution .

Comment: @HindDev: [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) is not compatible with [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer). So, if you want to "resume" a list that was started before, you'll have to manually set that up...

Comment: I think http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55001/38080 is much more easy to use

Comment: @Werner , thank you , but manually didn't give me the same bullet

Comment: I tried this before it inserts a duplicate frame I didn't like it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) is [incompatible](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31505/5764) with [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer). You can either [save the counter and re-use it later in the document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55000/5764), or use a `\label`-`\ref` approach for saving and restoring:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{refcount}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item one
    \item two
    \label{end-enumerate}% Save counter at end of enumerate
  \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \setcounterref{enumi}{end-enumerate}
    \item three
  \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The above requires you to use a separate for each `enumerate` list you want to "resume". If you're using this sequentially, then you can automate it to some extent:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{refcount}

\newcounter{saveenumi}
\newcommand{\saveenumerate}{%
  \stepcounter{saveenumi}%
  \label{saveenumi-\thesaveenumi}}
\newcommand{\restoreenumerate}{%
  \setcounterref{enumi}{saveenumi-\thesaveenumi}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item one
    \item two
    \saveenumerate
  \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \restoreenumerate
    \item three
  \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

`beamer` also provides it's own frame-specific overlay specification. In your minimal example, you can use:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item<-2> one
    \item<2> two
    \item<3> three
  \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you very much, it works, I didn't knew that in Latex we can use like a variable memories for saving a thing