# Beamer breaks enumitem when using [<+->]

Tags: beamer, enumitem, beamerarticle

In the MWE below, if I comment out the use of `enumitem` everything works fine, but with it included it breaks. Is there a way to have this working?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{title}

\begin{enumerate}[<+->]
    \item How
    \item are
    \item you?
\end{enumerate}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

If I use the following code I get the error: `Package enumitem Error: <+-> undefined.`

```
\documentclass{article}\usepackage{beamerarticle}

\mode<article>{\usepackage{enumitem}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{title}

\begin{enumerate}[<+->]
    \item How
    \item are
    \item you?
\end{enumerate}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You shouldn't load `enumitem` in `beamer`. Beamer already has its enumeration facilities, which are incompatible with `enumitem`'s.

Comment: Why do you want to use `enumitem`?

Comment: @samcarter I have one source file which can be used to create a beamer presentation, handouts and an article mode. I'm using the enumitem in the article mode.

Comment: @Geoff And for what do you need it in article mode? (Am just trying to find out if there isn't another way without the enumitem package)

Comment: @samcarter I can't answer that exactly, I'm probably using it for many purposes. One that comes to mind though is to `resume`.

Comment: @Geoff You could resume list like this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/298810/36296

Comment: @Geoff Would the same `enumerate` environment be present in your article and in your beamer version?

Comment: @samcarter It'll be easier for me to just delete the `\begin{enumerate}[<+->]` than it would to start changing all the uses of `enumitem`. That's why I posed the question the way I did.

Comment: @samcarter Actually all occurrences of `\begin{enumerate}[<+->]` are wrapped in frames a such `\begin{frame}<presentation>` so they play no role in the article mode (except to return errors).

Comment: @Geoff Could you have a look at my edited answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to load the `enumitem` package to use it in article mode, you can restrict the loading to this mode.

Then one just has to hide `[<+->]` from the `enumitem` package, which can be done with  `\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}` either globally or locally.

```
%\documentclass{beamer}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}

\mode<article>{
\usepackage{enumitem}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{title}

{
\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}% <- can also be used in the preamble if it should apply to all itemization/enumerate
\begin{enumerate}
    \item How
    \item are
    \item you?
\end{enumerate}
}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's a really elegant solution! Great! Many thanks!

Comment: @Geoff Nice to hear!