# Is there a better formatting option for an alternated enumerated/itemized list?

Tags: lists, enumerate, itemize, loops

I'm making a questions/answers page where answer follows the question. The questions are enumerated while the answers are not. Questions are using one color while answers using another one.

In order to pause numeration, I've used the solution provided to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25710/how-to-continue-enumerate-across-columns-in-beamer) question. As a result, my code looks like this in general:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
...
\newcounter{savedenum}
\newcommand*{\saveenum}{\setcounter{savedenum}{\theenumi}}
\newcommand*{\resume}{\setcounter{enumi}{\thesavedenum}}
...
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
...
\begin{document}
...
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item \color{black}{Question text goes here.}
    \saveenum
  \end{enumerate}

  \begin{itemize}
    \item[] \color{NavyBlue}{Answer text goes here.}
  \end{itemize}

  \begin{enumerate}
    \resume
    \item \color{black}{Question text goes here.}
    \saveenum
  \end{enumerate}

  \begin{itemize}
    \item[] \color{NavyBlue}{Answer text goes here.}
  \end{itemize}
...
\end{document}
```

Since there is a lot of code reuse, I'm seeking for a better solution (maybe a loop of some kind?), if possible, that will substitute the copy-and-paste of the `\begin{...} ... \end{...}` blocks.

Comment: You can use `\item[\textbullet]` for introducing the answer, staying in the same `enumerate` environment.

Comment: Did you try the [exercise](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/exercise) package?

Comment: I'd probably look in the direction of the theorem/ntheorem/amsthm packages to define an automatically-numbered `question` environment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest a different approach:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}

\newif\ifsolutions
\solutionstrue
\newenvironment{exercises}
 {\begin{enumerate}}
 {\end{enumerate}}
\newenvironment{question}
 {\item}
 {}
\ifsolutions
  \newenvironment{solution}
   {\par\nopagebreak\begingroup\color{NavyBlue}}
   {\endgroup}
\else
  \usepackage{comment}
  \excludecomment{solution}
\fi

\begin{document}
\begin{exercises}

\begin{question}
Question one text goes here.
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
Answer one text goes here.
\end{solution}

\begin{question}
Question two text goes here.
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
Answer two text goes here.
\end{solution}

\end{exercises}

\end{document}
```

The markup might seem excessive, but it allows for greater flexibility: you can customize `exercises` using `enumitem` features, but also `question` and `solution`. I've added a possibility: if you comment the

```
\solutionstrue
```

line, the solutions will not be printed at all.

#### Solutions active

[image]

#### Solutions suppressed

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Since you're already loading the [`enumitem`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/enumitem) package, here's a solution using the `resume` feature:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}

\newenvironment{question}{\enumerate[resume]\item}{\endenumerate}
\newenvironment{solution}{\itemize\item[]\begingroup\color{NavyBlue}}{\endgroup\enditemize}

\begin{document}

  \begin{question}
    Question text goes here.
  \end{question}
  \begin{solution}
    Answer text goes here.
  \end{solution}
  \begin{question}
    Question text goes here.
  \end{question}
  \begin{solution}
    Answer text goes here.
  \end{solution}
\end{document}
```

If you'd prefer to have your own `list` (perhaps you're using the `enumerate` environment outside of this task) then you could use a `newlist`

```
\newlist{myenumerate}{enumerate}{5}
\setlist[myenumerate]{label=\arabic*.,resume}

\newenvironment{question}{\myenumerate\item}{\endmyenumerate}
```

Finally, if you'd like to suppress the `solution`  environment, or perhaps output it to a separate file, I'd recommend looking at the [`answers`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/answers) package; you can switch the `answers` on and off in the main part of the document by using

```
% solutions written to file (NOT to main part of document)
\usepackage{answers}   
% solutions NOT written to file (written to main part of document)
\usepackage[nosolutionfiles]{answers}
```

Complete MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{answers}
%\usepackage[nosolutionfiles]{answers}

\newlist{myenumerate}{enumerate}{5}
\setlist[myenumerate]{label=\arabic*.,resume}

\newenvironment{question}{\myenumerate\item}{\endmyenumerate}

% open the answer file
\Opensolutionfile{shortsolutions}
\Newassociation{solution}{ShortSoln}{shortsolutions}

\begin{document}

\begin{question}
    Question text goes here.
    \begin{solution}
        Answer text goes here.
    \end{solution}
\end{question}
\begin{question}
    Question text goes here.
    \begin{solution}
        Answer text goes here.
    \end{solution}
\end{question}

% close the solutions files
\Closesolutionfile{shortsolutions}

\clearpage

% this just makes the displayed solutions use the itemize
% environment- makes the dispaly better
\renewenvironment{ShortSoln}[1]{%
\itemize\item[{\bfseries(#1)}]%
}%
{\enditemize}

% input the answers file
\section*{Answers}
\IfFileExists{shortsolutions.tex}{\input{shortsolutions.tex}}{}
\end{document}
```