# Why are A, B, C, and D not aligned? (tasks in beamer)

Tags: beamer, tasks

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tasks}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
    $1+1=$(\makebox[2cm]{})
        \begin{tasks}[counter-format = tsk[A]. ](2)
            \task one
            \task two
            \task three
            \task four
        \end{tasks}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A B C D  is not aligned ?

Comment: @clemens I get funny error messages here.

Comment: Seems to be incompatible beamer and tasks.

Comment: How to format the selection so that the four options are automatically aligned according to length

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The environment `tasks` wants to generate two columns. But, there seems to be a rounding issue, when the column width is calculated, because the text width is odd (`\showthe\numexpr\linewidth` gives 20138549 sp).

Making it even fixes the problem:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tasks}
\ifodd\textwidth
  \addtolength{\textwidth}{1sp}
\fi
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
    $1+1=(\makebox[2cm]{})$
    \begin{tasks}[counter-format = tsk[A]. ](2)
        \task one
        \task two
        \task three
        \task four
    \end{tasks}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

## Workaround:

I suggest using a simple `enumerate` environment instead. The label can be formatted with `\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{...}`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    $1+1=$(\makebox[2cm]{})
    {
        \setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{\Alph{enumi}.}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item one
            \item two
            \item three
            \item four
        \end{enumerate}
    }
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In case the items should be arranged in two columns, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25712/36296

Comment: I bet the second item should be in one line with the first, with the second line containing the third and fourth item.

Comment: @Johannes_B I did not see anything in the questions to assume this, but I added a link for two column enumeration in beamer.

Comment: `\begin{tasks}[counter-format = tsk[A]. ](2)` the numbere of columns is in the parentheses.

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks! (never came across the `tasks` package until now :)